# Handle 1 million records in Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui

Will the Kendo UI Grid be able to handle 1 million records? If not, how can I do pagination, filtering and sorting on the server? My server code is built using MVC.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data

Comment: We did not use server version, using java script version

Comment: See https://blog.falafel.com/server-paging-sorting-filtering-kendo-datasourcerequest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL server, you can take the paging & filtering object information through the controller read and pass that into a dynamic sql procedure.

You'll have to pass in the filters and paging info as parameters. The paging params can be used as offset / fetch for page size and number that you need. You'll want to include the filtering params to make sure everything stays in the right order.

This allows you to pull the data in chunks per page instead of pulling the entire data set each time.